# Отправить значение поля prompt в обработчик

Tags: javascript, prompt

Как отправить значение поля prompt в обработчик PHP на сервере для отправки сообщения.

Для этого Я написал код, но чего то не хватает, обработчик не видит значение поля prompt.

**Форма HTML**

```
<form style="display:none;" id="myform" action="mailer.php" method="POST">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var email = prompt("Ваш e-mail", "@");

        if (email != 'undefined') {
            document.getElementById("email").value;
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
        }
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

   //получаем e-mail
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    //проверка пустого поля
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) 
    exit();        
    //фильтр e-mail
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        exit();
    }
    //проверка e-mail
    if (!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_\-^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i", $_POST['email'])) 
    exit();

    mail(...);
    mail(...);
```

**Вопрос:**
Как отправить значение поля prompt в обработчик?

Answer (score 3):

Присвойте значение из переменной javascript элементу на странице.
Тут

```
        document.getElementById("email").value;
```

не выполняете ни каких действий. Делайте присвоение

```
        document.getElementById("email").value = email;
```

**UPD**

Рабочий пример (файл 1.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
   var_dump($_POST);
   exit();
}
?>
<form style="display:none;" id="myform" action="1.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
</form>
<script>
var email = prompt("Ваш e-mail", "@");
if (email != 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById("email").value = email;
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Visman, я уже делал так. Только onClick здесь в окне.

Comment: @Viher, добавил в ответ рабочий пример.

Comment: спасибо! Я нашел увидел свою ошибку `if (isset($_POST['email'])){`